# YUI autocomplete: how to make container width adjust to content

Tags: javascript, yui

In [YUI 2 autocomplete](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_basic_array.html) how to make the container that holds the suggestions automatically adjust the width to the longest element irrespective of the width of the input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
<div class="yui-skin-sam"><div id="autocomplete"></div></div>
```

and

```
.yui-skin-sam .yui-ac-content {
    width:auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the container's width according to the input length :

suppose your input length is 20px:

```
.yui-skin-sam .yui-ac-container { width:20px;left:0px;}
```

Comment: I want the container to adopt a width of the longest element in the list and if necessary be wider than input. This will only make it the width of input.